Can I work mostly remotely from Switzerland in Germany without losing my permit C?
I have a permit C in Switzerland.
I was offered a good position in Germany.
Can I start working in Germany from Switzerland (mostly remotely),
without losing my Permit C?

Is your potential employer planning to sponsor you for work authorization in Germany?

According to https://www.legalexpat.ch/swiss-permit/permit-c/ a Swiss C permit is the equivalent of Swiss permanent residency, allowing a non-Swiss citizen to work and live in Switzerland without any restrictions. A permit C holder does not need an authorization to change employment or to work as an independent. Additionally, the C permit does not restrict employment to a specific canton (art. 34 LEI).
So it looks like the answer is Yes, however if I were you I would get confirmation from an Immigration adviser.

All of that applies for working in Switzerland.
But what, if I would work abroad?
Leaving Switzerland for too long - makes Permit C becoming invalid.
"Sie kann im Fall einer Auslandabwesenheit von mehr als sechs
Monaten nur dann fortbestehen, wenn der Ausländer tatsächlich die Absicht hat,
innerhalb der Höchstfrist von vier Jahren wieder in die Schweiz zurückzukehren"
https://www.zh.ch/content/dam/zhweb/bilder-dokumente/themen/migration-integration/einreise-aufenthalt/weisungen/Aufrechterhaltung%20der%20Niederlassungsbewilligung.pdf

@Skip this question is about working "mostly remotely."  If you want to ask about retaining your C permit while spending longer periods of time in Germany, it would probably be best to post a new question.  (In fact, you likely need a German work permit to work at all at your German employer's office.  If you work 100% remotely from Switzerland then the question is primarily one of income tax withholding and payroll taxes.)
